# GIT Create a new branch from initial state of commit without loss the on going work

Tags: git

i have need to create a new branch on which just need to have the files exactly like they was in the previous commit, excluding the modifications and exclude the new added files. The problem is that i  need to keep the current modifications over the same files and the new ones on the master branch. This is because in middle on a planned work something urgent came up. I dont know how exactly GIT allows to manage those scenarios.

I have tried **git stash** but the problem is that it remove the modified files from the file system too, i just need to keep them just like they was on previous commit

Comment: Did you try checking out the previous commit by its hash? You can git the value from `git log` then you can checkout a new branch from that state, leaving master in tact.

Comment: It creates the new branch with the same uncommit / untracket files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this - one is with `git branch <sha1hash>` using the commit ID of the commit you'd like to branch from.

Alternatively, you could branch now, and let all of the changes be moved to the new branch. When you checkout to a different branch, the index and staging area move with you, so you could checkout back to master and bring those files with you again, leaving the index and staging area of the new branch clean.